# NHibernate SchemaExport string property map char(n) instead of varchar(n)

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to generate my tables using `SchemaExport` like this:

```
_sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                .ConnectionString(connectionString))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyClass>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true,false))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

It works, but it creates columns mapped by my string properties as `nvarchar(n)` or `varchar(n)`. I really need to create them as `char(n)`, because I am sure their lengths are constant.

I have tried following:

```
Map(x => x.MyString, "COLUMN").CustomType("char").Length(7); //-> varchar(7)
Map(x => x.MyString, "COLUMN").CustomType("AnsiString").Length(7); //-> varchar(7)
Map(x => x.MyString, "COLUMN").Length(7); //-> nvarchar(7)
Map(x => x.MyString, "COLUMN").CustomSqlType("char").Length(7); //-> char(1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I solved the issue by myself:

```
Map(x => x.MyString, "COLUMN").CustomSqlType("char(7)");
```